# Incompatible Types: void cannot be converted to int, Pixel related

Tags: java

EDIT: I have tried to use the other question to answer my own, but changing the return type of the method is not helping. I am still lost. 
I am fairly new to Java, so I am sorry if the coding is weird. However, I am trying to make a program that takes an image, and uses a nest loop to change every single pixel value. So, I am trying to make the image turn "negative" by subtracting each pixel value from 255. Here is my program:

```
import java.awt.*;           
class TrueColors
{
    TrueColors()       
    {
    }

    public void negative()
    {
        Picture pictureObj = new Picture("washingtonmonument.jpg");     //creates a new Picture object representing the file in the parameter list                 
        pictureObj.explore();                                           //explore the Picture object which is currently the unaltered original image
        int redValue = 0; int greenValue = 0; int blueValue = 0;        //declare and initialize the variables that hold the red, green, and blue values (0-255)

        Pixel targetPixel = new Pixel(pictureObj, 0,0);                //set the coordinate for the image origin
        Color pixelColor = null;                                        //declare a Color object and set its initial value to null (or nothing)          

        for(int y=0; y < pictureObj.getHeight(); y++)                   //outside nested loop to traverse the image from top to bottom
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < pictureObj.getWidth(); x++)              //inside nested loop to traverse the image from left to right
            {
                targetPixel = pictureObj.getPixel(x,y);                 //gets the x,y coordinate of the target pixel
                pixelColor = targetPixel.getColor();                    //gets the color of the target pixel

                redValue = pixelColor.getRed();                         //assign the red component (0-255) of the target pixel to the redValue variable 
                greenValue = pixelColor.getGreen();                     //assign the green component (0-255) of the target pixel to the greenValue variable
                blueValue = pixelColor.getBlue();                       //assign the blue component (0-255) of the target pixel to the blueValue variable
                redValue = targetPixel.setRed(255-redValue);
                greenValue = targetPixel.setGreen(255-greenValue);
                blueValue = targetPixel.setBlue(255-blueValue);
                pixelColor = new Color(redValue, greenValue, blueValue);    
                targetPixel.setColor(pixelColor);                           

            }//end of the inner for loop
        }//end of the outer for loop
        pictureObj.explore();                                           //explore the Picture object which is now the altered image
        pictureObj.write("NewWashingtonMonument.jpg");                  //write the altered Picture object to a new file
        pictureObj.show();                                              //show the altered Picture object (not in the explore tool)
    }
}

public class TrueColorsTester                                                 //start of the class
{
    public static void main(String[] args)                              //start of the main method
    {
        TrueColors tc = new TrueColors();

        tc.negative();


    }//end of main method
}//end of class
```

So, when I compile this code I get the error: "Incompatible Types: void cannot be converted to int" and it highlights:

```
redValue = targetPixel.setRed(255-redValue);
```

Specifically the 255-redValue. I assume that this would occur with each statement where I try to subtract the value from 255. Could someone please help?

Comment: This method: `targetPixel.setRed(255-redValue);` returns void, nothing. So don't use it to try to assign a value to an int variable.

Comment: You need to learn the basic difference between a setter method and a getter method.

Comment: A `void` method doesn't return a value.  `setRed` is a void method.  Therefore, when you say `redValue = targetPixel.setRed(255-redValue);`, it doesn't work because you're telling the program to assign something to `redValue`, but `setRed` doesn't return a value so there's nothing to assign to it.  To fix it, figure out: what value do you want `redValue` to be after this statement?  You have to answer this.  I have no clue what you want.  Once you figure it out, then write assignment that sets `redValue` to that value.